# Icon name in win32 resources?

Tags: winapi, resources

I am writing a Win32 app (extract.exe) to list or extract ICONs or other resources in a module's resources (EXE or DLL). The app is written in C. It fails on 'FindResource()', I believe because of an incorrect name. The target app (app.exe) contains the following in it's RC script (app.rc):

```
MYICON                 ICON    DISCARDABLE     "app.ico"
MYRCDATA               RCDATA  DISCARDABLE     "hello.txt"
```

I've examined the resources of app.exe with various third-party tools and my own apps: the resource name of the icon is displayed a **"1"** rather than **"MYICON"**, but the name of the RCDATA correctly shows as **"MYRCDATA"**.

I've confirmed that "app.ico" is a valid .ico file but still no joy.

**What am I missing here?**

Notes: I'm running win10/64 on a Dell machine and compiling with MS Visual C.

Comment: Do you have a line like `#define MYICON 1` somewhere in a header file?

Comment: To add to the previous comment, the icon ID is most likely the *number* `1` not the *string* `"1"`. That's commonly done because the lowest ID is what Windows uses as the app icon by default.

Comment: If `app.rc` has a `#define` statement (directly, or via an `#include`) that defines `MYICON` as a number, make sure the source file that is calling `FindResource()` is also `#include`'ing/`#define`'ing `MYICON` the same way, and then you can pass `MAKEINTRESOURCE(MYICON)` to `FindResource()` as the resource ID to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out. Apparently, the resource compiler splits an icon file into two parts: (1) an "icon directory" (aka "RT_GROUP_ICON") and (2) the icon itself. The directory contains a 6-byte header and one or more 16-byte entries that include the integer "ID" of the actual icon (1 in my case). The format of directory entries is:

```
typedef struct    // This is the Directory Entry stored in resources
{
   BYTE Width;
   BYTE Height;
   BYTE Colors;
   BYTE Reserved;
   WORD Planes;
   WORD BitsPerPixel;
   DWORD ImageSize;
   WORD ResourceID
} IconDirResEntry, *PIconDirResEntry;
```

A good description of this can be found in
https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c12873/Hacking-Icon-Resources.htm

In my case, resource "MYICON" is the RT_GROUP_ICON icon directory which contains ID value of "1".